# CSS Selection JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

I am not a JQUERY Expert and want to know if its possible to select "Items with no id defined that are nested and have a certain css class defined" ?

Example:

When I look at the downloaded CSS and match rules here is the `div`:

```
<div id="type" class="productType">Test Descript <span>$399.00</span> </div>
```

The CSS that gets applied to the span is:

```
.rightInfoDiv h1 div.productType {font-size: 14px;line-height: 18px;font-weight: normal;margin-bottom: 0.1em;}
```

I want to be able to select the "span" so I can get a price. Is this possible ? Any pointers would be appreciated

Thanks very much

Answer (score 3):

You can target the parent div and then target the child-span

```
var price = $('#type').children('span').text();
console.log(price); // will output $399.00
```

Comment: what if there would be more span tags?

Comment: You could use .eq() to target the one you're after.
.children('span').eq(0) - will target the first span, .eq(1) the second etc etc..

However it would be better to give the price span a class, and just target it directly.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't uderstand that statement: "Items with no id defined that are nested and have a certain css class defined". Items doesn't need to have any id or even class. If you want to do that just:

```
var spans = $('.productType span');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
var x = $("#type span").text();
```

`x` is now `$399.00`

Answer (score 0):

```
var item = $("#type span").text();
```

Demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/UXtJD/